# Use child scope's data for parent scope's ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Update 2 added, see below**

First of all, this is the starting point of the framework I am working with (and needs to fix):

```
// index.html
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="outerController">
      <div id="copy"></div>
      <hr>
      <div id="src" ng-controller="innerController">
        <table>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="poke in pokemon">
              <td>{{ poke.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ poke.type }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Pikachu</td>
              <td>Electric</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

// index.js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("innerController", function($scope) {
  $scope.pokemon = [{
    name: "Bulbasaur",
    type: "Grass/Poison"
  }, {
    name: "Charmander",
    type: "Fire"
  }, {
    name: "Squirtle",
    type: "Water"
  }];
});

app.controller("outerController", function($scope) {
  $("#copy").html($("#src").html());
});
```

So as you can see, the child controller will generate a table from its scope's data via `ng-repeat`. This step is successful. The next step is for the parent controller to copy-paste the inner HTML from `src` to `copy`. The intent is for `copy` to contain a copy of the complete table fully generated by angularJS inside `src`.

This step has failed. Only the table headers and the static Pikachu row is visible. After doing some research I am certain that this is because `pokemon` is inside the child controller's scope which is inaccessible by the parent controller. The HTML copied into the `copy` container includes the entire `ng-repeat` directive. This copied directive is inside the parent scope, where `$scope.pokemon` does not exist/contains no data, which is why the `ng-repeat` in `copy` generated nothing.

I cannot put the data inside the parent controller. In my actual application, the system uses a modular design. Each inner controller represents a module which pulls its own set of data from the server. There are multiple web pages (represented by the outer controller) which have a many-to-many relationship with the modules, and the composition of modules in each web page needs to be modifiable. That means the data used by a module must be contained within itself.

How can I rectify this?

**Update 1**: Redacted. I posted an example of using `$emit` and `$on` but Robert's example should be assumed as correct, since I'm still very new to this. Refer to his answer.

**Update 2**: While testing Alvaro Vazquez's & Robert's solutions, I've identified the specific root cause. When `$("#copy").html($("#src").html());` is executed, either the copied `ng-repeat` executed before any data transfer to `outerController` occurred, or it was never executed. In the end, modifying what I originally did above makes it fully working:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

$(function() {
  $("#copy").html($("#src").html());
});

app.controller("innerController", function($scope) {
  $scope.pokemon = [{
    name: "Bulbasaur",
    type: "Grass/Poison"
  }, {
    name: "Charmander",
    type: "Fire"
  }, {
    name: "Squirtle",
    type: "Water"
  }];
});

app.controller("outerController", function($scope) {
  $scope.pokemon = [{
    name: "Bulbasaur",
    type: "Grass/Poison"
  }, {
    name: "Charmander",
    type: "Fire"
  }, {
    name: "Squirtle",
    type: "Water"
  }];
});
```

With the location of that particular statement changed, all that is left is to transfer the data to `outerController`, and at this point both Alvaro's and Robert's solutions work.

As an aside, I think some have advised against using `$("#copy").html($("#src").html());`. As I have partly described in the comments, the actual application I'm developing consists of multiple web pages, each containing its own `outerController`. Each `innerController` is in its own separate HTML file added via an include directive into `src`. The `outerController` copies the inner HTML of `src`, passes it to a third party library, which pastes it into `copy` and controls its visual layout. `$("#copy").html($("#src").html());` is actually part of the third party library's implementation, so I can't change that. Using this statement is therefore a requirement.

I'll post the above as a solution when I get home and has the convenience of a PC keyboard. In the meantime feel free to recommend better solutions to what is found if you have one, thanks!

Comment: Are you willing to move your data array (in this case your pokemon array) to an angular serice? this way you could retrieve the data from the server from that service, and then access the data in any controller you would like. I think that is the best design idea, and if you are open to it I could post an answer.

Comment: @AlvaroVazquez Well go ahead and post your answer. This project is still in a rather experimental stage so the focus is on trying to get the desired functionalities working.

Comment: If this is the starting point of a framework that's going to be built upon angular then you should stick to that and don't mix basic function with jQuery. If you know a way where jQuery will solve your problem then there's almost allways a angular way of doing that as well.

Comment: @thegreatjedi there you have my response, hope it helps :) I really encourage you to make good use of the MVC pattern. In fact, the main reason for using AngularJS is to be able to use that pattern in a reasonably easy way ;)

Comment: @MarcusH are you referring to the part where I want to copy the HTML from `src` into `copy`? Sorry but I simplified that from the actual system. In the actual system, `src` is being passed by the outer controller into a third party library (which apparently also uses angularJS) which controls the layout of what goes into `copy`. The library actually takes the `id` of what we want copied as a parameter, not the `html()` (that's inside the library's implementation). I can't do anything about this part, it's a feature my organisation wants to add so my task is to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make use of angular services.

### Declaring a service

First of all, you should declare a service which would 'serve' the data to the rest of your application. For the sake of simplicity, I will only show a method which returns a predefined array, but you could get the data from the server here.

```
app.service('pokemonService', function () {
    return {
        getPokemon: function () {
            return [{
                  name: "Bulbasaur",
                  type: "Grass/Poison"
              }, {
                  name: "Charmander",
                  type: "Fire"
              }, {
                  name: "Squirtle",
                  type: "Water"
              }];
        }
    };
});
```

### Using the service in your controller

Then, you can use the service on any of your controllers, injecting it as any other predefined angular service:

```
app.controller('innerController', function($scope, pokemonService) {
    $scope.pokemon = pokemonService.getPokemon();
});

app.controller('outerController', function($scope, pokemonService) {
    $scope.outerPokemon = pokemonService.getPokemon();
});
```

### Showing the data in your view

Finally, you can list all your pokémon in any template/part of the template you want:

```
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="outerController">
      <div id="copy">
          <!-- Here you can also list the pokémon from your outerController, maybe this time in a list -->
          <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="poke in pokemonOuter">
                  {{ poke.name }} - <span class="type">{{ poke.type }}</span>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div id="src" ng-controller="innerController">
        <table>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="poke in pokemon">
              <td>{{ poke.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ poke.type }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Wrap up

As you can see, there is no need of messing with the DOM at all. If you use AngularJS, you should do things the Angular way, and working directly with the DOM is not the Angular way at all. Instead, you should put all your  data and business logic into services, then use those services in your controllers to retrieve that data and pass it to the view.

Comment: You forgot to inject the pokemonService in outerController

Comment: Oops, you are right! I edited my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Scopes in Angular uses prototypal inheritance, so the child scope will have access to the parent properties but the parent will not have access to the child controller scope properties.

You can use a service to share data or use $emit to send events upwards (upwards until the root scope).

I created a plnkr for you to show you how to use emit (you can find it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9SnK4zHgHPpoiYRrKdpu?p=preview))

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("outerController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  console.log('aici');
  $scope.$on('pokemonEvent', function(event, mass) { console.log(mass); });

}]); 

app.controller("innerController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pokemon = [{
    name: "Bulbasaur",
    type: "Grass/Poison"
  }, {
    name: "Charmander",
    type: "Fire"
  }, {
    name: "Squirtle",
    type: "Water"
  }];

  $scope.$emit('pokemonEvent', $scope.pokemon);
}]);
```

Comment: I actually tried that but it didn't work. idk if I did it right though. Take a look at my update to the quesiton.